# Deriving from templatized base class

Tags: c++, c++11

I've to buil a small database of different kinds type of objects. Is it a good idea have a base templatized class, let's call it Database and then let derive other classes from that.

For example:

```
template< typename Record,
          size_t RECORD_SIZE,
          char RECORD_SEP = '!',
          char RECORD_PARAM_SEP = ',',
          char RECORD_FIELD_SEP = '~',
          size_t MAX_RECORDS_PER_QUERY = 5000,
          size_t MIN_RECORD_COUNT = 15000
          >
class Database
{
public:
    typedef Record Record_t;
    typedef std::vector< unsigned char > QueryBuffer;
    Database( const std::string& basePath, const std::string& recordPath, const std::string tableFilename );

    enum class QueryResult
    {
        OK,
        NO_DATA,
        OVERFLOW,
        FUTURE_DATE,
        FUTURE_RANGE,
        ERROR
    };

    void add( void add( const Record_t& r )
    {
        Lock lock( mMutex );
        // ... lots of stuff here
    }

    QueryResult query(QueryBuffer &qb, time_t first, time_t last )
    {
        Lock lock( mMutex );

        // ... lots of stuff here
    }

    QueryResult query(QueryBuffer &qb, time_t first )
    {
        Lock lock( mMutex );

        // ... lots of stuff here
    }

    // protected and private data
};
```

Then derive the class in this way

```
class GameDatabase : public Database< GameType, 9 >
{
private:
    using MyBase Database< GameType, 9 >;

public:
    GameDatabase( const std::string& basePath )
        : MyBase{ basePath, "g/", "g.dat" }
    {
    }

    // another query method
    QueryResult query(QueryBuffer &qb, size_t first, size_t last )
    {
        Lock lock( mMutex );

        // use protected methods of MyBase

        // .... lots of stuff here      
    }
};
```

Is this a good idea or are better solution? The problem is that definition of Database must be all inlined, and this is long code.

Comment: "The problem is that definition of Database must be all inlined" - Is that a project requirement and the requirement is the problem, or is it a problem that templates require implementations in headers?

Comment: @SebastianRedl no I've no project requirment, the only problem is that implementation must be in headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an unusual idiom, but ordinarily the template parameters are either types, or integers which need to be compile-time. What are you hoping to gain by compiling your sizes and delimiters in like that?

I suggest you make them members of Database, initialized in the constructor. If you want to inline everything, go right ahead. But don't make things template parameters when you just need them to be const.

Comment: Okay, they can be initialized in the ctor (except Record).

Comment: I've a problem: Record need to have the overload operator << defined as `std::ostream& operator << ( std::ostream& os, const Record_t& rec )` and Database need it in the `add` function. How can I go around?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to implement template members inline, they just need to be in headers. A common idiom is to have a separate header for the implementation and include it at the bottom of the main header.

```
// foo.hpp
template <typename T>
class foo {
public:
  void bar();
};

#include "foo.tpp"

// foo.tpp
template <typename T>
void foo<T>::bar() { /* code here */ }
```

Comment: what is the exact syntax in this case?

Comment: I found it my self. The syntax in this case must be. `template <typename T> void foo<T>::bar() {}`

Comment: Ah, sorry. Fixed in my post.